# "Class 'Phar' not found" error setting up WP-CLI with Cygwin

Tags: wp-cli, xampp

I'm trying to install the WP-CLI tools [as described here](https://wp-cli.org/#installing) using Cygwin, which the guide claims is supported.

When doing:

```
cd /XAMPP/htdocs
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
php wp-cli.phar --info
```

It fails with the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Phar' not found in /cygdrive/b/Users/User/Desktop/XAMPP/htdocs/wp-cli.phar:3 Stack trace:
>       #0 {main}   thrown in /cygdrive/b/Users/User/Desktop/XAMPP/htdocs/wp-cli.phar on line 3

What's causing this error, and how can I successfully get WP-CLI running
under Cygwin?

Comment: Install Phar. https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.setup.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the Phar extension or it's not enabled. Which version of PHP are you actually running? Check it with `php --version`.

> The Phar extension is bundled with PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0, and enabled by default.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php.

Your best bet is to upgrade PHP to at least PHP 7.1. Alternatively follow other guides around here to either get and enable Phar, or calling WP-CLI with a different PHP version.

See [PHP: Class 'Phar' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8851099/2199525).

---

Finally this one may turn out as a big helper as well: [Cygwin and Xampp, wrong PHP is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34018625/2199525). To have Cygwin use XAMPP's PHP instead its own call the following command every time you restart Cygwin or add it to its `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to be permanent.

> ```
> export PATH=/cygdrive/c/xampp/php:$PATH
> ```

Comment: Thank you, it did turn out that the issue was that I was using Cygwin's own PHP rather than XAMPP's; however, even with this rectified, I'm still getting a separate error that doesn't allow me to run WP-CLI from anywhere except the directory it's contained in. I've created a question here for that error: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340648/could-not-open-input-file-error-even-when-wp-cli-is-in-the-path.