# "Could not open input file" error even when WP-CLI is in the path

Tags: wp-cli, xampp

I'm developing Wordpress locally with XAMPP, and currently trying to install the WP-CLI tools [as described here](https://wp-cli.org/#installing) using Cygwin.

I renamed `wp-cli.phar` to `wp`, made it executable and moved it to the `XAMPP/php` folder.

However, running `wp` gives me the error:

> Could not open input file: /cygdrive/b/Users/User/Desktop/XAMPP/php/wp

On the other hand, doing `./wp` from the directory that the file is located in runs the program without issue.

This is despite the fact that both `/cygdrive/b/Users/User/Desktop/XAMPP/php` and `/cygdrive/b/Users/User/Desktop/XAMPP/php/wp` are in my PATH, via Cygwin's `~/.bash_profile` file.

This is confirmed by doing `which php`:

```
/cygdrive/b/Users/User/Desktop/XAMPP/php/php
```

...and `which wp`:

```
/cygdrive/b/Users/User/Desktop/XAMPP/php/wp
```

**What could be causing this problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to scrape together enough information from disparate sources to figure out how to fix this, because - as I'm increasingly finding with anything related to Wordpress development - the documentation is so woefully inadequate.

The fact that it took so much research and hacking together on my part just to get an official command-line utility working on a platform that it claims to support is ridiculous, and my estimation of the Wordpress project and the Automattic team has dropped massively over the last few weeks for such reasons.

What follows in this answer adapts information from [aefxx's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276946/composer-cygwin/14904607#14904607) and [leymannx's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/340662/167562) to this question.

As far I can tell, the issue here is that `php.exe` - the PHP binary included with XAMPP, WAMP and similar local servers - is a Windows binary that only understands paths in Windows format. The solution, as coded by *aefxx* in his answer, is to use a wrapper script that checks for Unix-style paths passed to the PHP binary and converts them into Windows paths that it can understand.

Note that because this solution is implemented as a wrapper to the PHP binary itself, it should work to solve this issue for any PHP program running under Cygwin, not just WP-CLI.

### How to get WP-CLI working with Cygwin

**Remember to replace any paths below with your own.**

Once you've downloaded the `wp-cli.phar` file and made it executable [as detailed in the documentation](https://wp-cli.org/#install), move it to where you want to install it - `/usr/local/bin` tends to be the convention for user-installed binaries on Linux, or inside of XAMPP's PHP server root if you're using XAMPP - and rename it to something easier to type, like `wp`:

```
mv wp-cli.phar /cygdrive/c/XAMPP/php/wp
```

Then, navigate to the new install directory and create a wrapper file called `php`:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/XAMPP/php/wp &&
touch php &&
chmod +x ./php
```

Open the file in a text editor and paste the following into it, replacing the path to the PHP executable with your own:

```
#!/bin/bash

php="/cygdrive/c/XAMPP/php/php.exe"

for ((n=1; n <= $#; n++)); do
    if [ -e "${!n}" ]; then
        # Converts Unix style paths to Windows equivalents
        path="$(cygpath --mixed ${!n} | xargs)"

        case 1 in
            $(( n == 1 )) )
                set -- "$path" "${@:$(($n+1))}";;
            $(( n < $# )) )
                set -- "${@:1:$((n-1))}" "$path" ${@:$((n+1)):$#};;
            *)
                set -- "${@:1:$(($#-1))}" "$path";;
        esac
    fi
done

"$php" "$@"
```

Finally, run `wp` to confirm that WP-CLI - and any other PHP tools requiring a Cygwin wrapper - is now working on Cygwin.

Comment: Seems legit. Only thing I'd do is to get rid of the `wp` alias. Since the `wp-cli.phar` does include a PHP shebang, you should be able to call it directly - i.e. as long as the wrapper is in your `PATH`.

Comment: @aefxx You're right. I could have sworn when testing yesterday that the alias was crucial in getting the whole thing to work, along with the wrapper, but sure enough removing it today doesn't seem to make a difference. Edited accordingly, thank you.

Comment: Glad, it's working for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two interesting questions on SO:

- [Cygwin and PHPUnit: Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2266661/2199525)
- [Composer & Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12276946/2199525)

The easiest seems to be putting an alias into your Cygwin's `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias wp="/cygdrive/b/Users/User/XAMPP/php/php /cygdrive/b/Users/User/XAMPP/php/wp"
```

Comment: That's a hacky solution, but I'll take it since it seems like the best one. I understand that the alias is calling the absolute links to both the `php` and `wp` binaries, but do you have any idea why that's necessary to do?

Comment: @Hashim – No clue to be honest. Some answers in the linked questions suggest it's Windows paths, some suggest its confusing PHP binaries... The alias then seems to be the least intrusive and the quickest fix at all; win win.

Comment: Scratch that, looks like I spoke too soon. Not even the alias allows `wp` to work. My actual path has a space in it, so I'm trying to nest both paths in single quotes, which gives me: `alias wp="'/cygdrive/b/Users/User/Charity Website/XAMPP/php/php' '/cygdrive/b/Users/User/Charity Website/XAMPP/php/wp'"`. Adding this to ~/.bashrc and sourcing it doesn't make any difference, the same error persists.

Comment: @Hashim – Damn! Unfortunately I have no Windows at hand to test it myself any time soon. I edited my answer to unlock your vote, maybe you can unaccept my answer now?